# create multiple db connections in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

if I have an array of server ip addresses:

```
 $servers = array('1.2.3.4','4.5.6.7','7.8.9.10');
```

how can i loop through them and connect to db, get data from each server, then close?

```
 foreach ($servers as $v){
    $bdb = new PDO('mysql:host='.$v.';dbname=someDB','user','pass');
    $sel = "SELECT data from table";
    $stmt = $bdb->query($sel);
    while($r = $stmt->fetch()){
          $result[$v]['data'] = $r['data'];
    }
 }
```

My desired result would be:

```
    print_r($result);

 array
 (
     [1.2.3.4] => Array
                 (
                   [data] => 'someData'
                 )
     [2.3.4.5] => Array
                 (
                   [data] => 'someOtherData'
                 )
     [7.8.9.10] => Array
                 (
                   [data] => 'someOtherOtherData'
                 )
  )
```

currently the above code only produces results from the first value in servers array.

I have tried setting $bdb=NULL and unset($bdb) with no luck

Comment: Are you sure each connection is successful? Also, you have a typo in your connection string as posted (missing a closing `'`)

Comment: try printing the query result after you run the SELECT statement to see the error you're running into. I'm assuming you have the same user and password for all of servers?

Comment: connecting to db via command line from server connects ok.

Comment: yes, same u/p for all servers.

Comment: if i comment out the pdo connection and add echo $v.  it displays all ip addresses correctly.  it seems like the 2nd instance of the pdo class causes an error, but i dont see any error..

Comment: In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $v with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to close the connection after every iteration. Otherwise you have to build an array with connections and don't same them everytime in the same variable.

```
foreach ($servers as $v){
    $bdb = new PDO('mysql:host='.$v.';dbname=someDB','user','pass');
    $sel = "SELECT data from table";
    $stmt = $bdb->query($sel);
    while($r = $stmt->fetch()){
          $result[$v]['data'] = $r['data'];
    }
    $bdb = null;
}
```

It should work if you close the connection in that way set your variable to null and delete the connection. Then it should be possible to make a new one in the next iteration.

Comment: i was unsetting bdb in the while statement. not after it was over.